# Why does this Java Mail call fail in JDK 1.5, but succeed in 1.6?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, java-6, java-5

When I run the following code with JDK 1.5, the last line fails, but when I run it with JDK 1.6 it succeeds.  Why is this?

Code:

```
Session session;
session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,
new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }
});

// Create a default MimeMessage object.
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
```

Comment: In what way does it fail; what is the error or exception plus relevant stack trace, or does it simply not compile?  Are you using the same mail.jar and activation.jar libraries for both JREs?

Comment: I'm actually running it on my host provider and calling a servlet using ajax, so the only feedback I get is an error 200 on the ajax request.  But I narrowed down the line of code where it is actually failing.

Comment: So would you be able to place a try/catch around the constructor call and output the stack trace of the `Exception` then?

Comment: I actually did that and it won't catch. I put this: 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            json.put("title", "Failed!");
            json.put("message", "Program failed!");
            out.print(json);
        }

Comment: It may be an `Error`; try catching a `Throwable`, not an `Exception`, and call `ex.printStackTrace();` and `out.print(ex.getMessage());`.

Comment: this is what I get: 'javax/activation/DataSource'

Comment: I think I have to add the activation.jar file.  I don't think that .jar is included in jdk 1.5

Comment: Yes that was the problem.  I needed to add the activation.jar library to my project since it is running on jdk 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Drew conclusion through asking questions on comments that the activation JAR was missing.